# Long equation merging into text of second column in double column IEEEtran.cls format

Tags: equations, split

[image: I am writing a long equation using \begin{equation} and then \begin{split}, but it is merging into the text of the second column as shown in the figure. However, there is sufficient space on the left side of the equation. I have used multiline, fleqn, aligned, aligned, but nothing helped me. The packages I am using are given below]

```
     \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \usepackage{tablefootnote}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{placeins} 
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{float,caption}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \usepackage{textcomp}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{ mathrsfs }
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \providecommand{\nr}[1]{\textcolor{red}{[{\bf #1}]}}
    \newcommand{\subparagraph}{}
    \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
    \usepackage{cuted}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
    \renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Make the equation shorter. As you are not providing any sort of code or viable picture this is the only advice you'll get.

Comment: I am not able to short the equation, as I tried a lot

Comment: You are (1) not providing the code for the equation and (2) actively censoring the image such that we cannot see it. What kind of help are you expecting?

Comment: Please show the equation. With not seeing it we cant help you. BTW, do you really need all those packages loaded in preamble (where some of packages related to math are loaded three times!)?

Comment: I do not know and I have not tried but maybe `\resizebox{}{}{}` command can be useful for this occasion.

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment and just guessing ... however, you may get an idea, what you can do (at least at preparing your MWE, which we need and cleaning your preamble):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\usepackage{url} loaded by hyperref
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%%%% collected to math related packages, which one you really need?
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also load amsmath
%\usepackage{ mathrsfs }

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float,caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\providecommand{\nr}[1]{\textcolor{red}{[{\bf #1}]}}
\newcommand{\subparagraph}{}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}    % added for text filler
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{multline} % equation is a slightly shorter now ...
\text{short left part} =    \\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \text{very, very, very ,very  long right part of equation}
    \end{multline}
\lipsum[2-11]
\end{document}
```

result:

[image]